# Get item ID from populated ListView

Tags: android, database, listview

I need help retrieve my ListView items ID, to add delete functionality.
My ListView is populated with this code:

```
ListView BookList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    DbAdapter db = new DbAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    db.open();
    Cursor cursor = db.fetchAllBooks();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.book, cursor, new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,DbAdapter.KEY_AUTHOR},new int[]{R.id.booktitle,R.id.bookauthor});
    BookList.setAdapter(adapter);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
```

My delete code is set as this, in the DbAdapter class:

```
//delete a book      
public boolean deleteBook(long bookID) {
return database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_BOOKID + "=" + bookID, null) > 0;
}
```

Any help?

Full sources:  pastebin.com/kKgePkPM

Comment: can you please post whole code?

Comment: @Ȃŵåiṩĸîŋg : here you have: http://pastebin.com/kKgePkPM
The delete event should be inserted to line 80.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can add itemclicklistener to your listview, then use the row id to remove it from your database, if the bookid is the same as the row id of course.

```
BookList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

       if (db.deleteBook(position)) { // Success!
            // remove from listview data source here
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }


    }
  });
```

Comment: The items are not 'clickable'. I have to do it by clicking Delete button next to the item.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a listener to your listView. The best way is set

```
bookList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {                    
    // DO YOUR STUFF HERE 
    }        
});
```

There you will get the view and the position clicked. With the view or the position you could obtain the value desired to your "deletebook" method.

Comment: The items are not 'clickable'. I have to do it by clicking Delete button next to the item.

Comment: Then you have to develop a custom adapter, with a custom layout. And Assign the onclicklistener to that button.

Comment: I already have a custom adapter, with custom layout associated. How to assign onclicklistener?

Comment: deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
db.deleteBook(position);
}

Comment: An error: "The method remove(int) is undefined for the type ListView"

Answer (score 0):

try adding something like this in `getView` method:

```
Button btnDelete = (Button) convertedRowView.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteCustom);
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int itemPos = 4; // This is position of item in ArrayList
        deleteBook(getItemId(itemPos));
    }
});
```

Comment: Where's defined getItemId?

Comment: in your custom adapter.

Comment: Look here: pastebin.com/kKgePkPM (here's my Adapter)

Comment: I think you should use `onItemClickListener` or `onItemLongClickListener` in your ListView.

Comment: I think it too, but really don't know how to add, can you guide me?

Comment: can you send me whole project?
or contact me on FB, so we can chat everything about your project

Comment: My FB: fb.com/Awais.is.King
My Email: awaisking.magician@gmail.com